# How to preseve Execute permissions for MySQL procedure with alter procedure (Drop/Create)

Tags: mysql, permissions

In MySQL you can not alter procedure rather you have to perform drop/create procedure to alter the body of the procedure. The problem is doing drop/create also removes the execute permissions given on that selected procedure.

Is there any way of giving permanent execute permissions that remains even after drop/create procedure.

A sample code to verify is as below

> delimiter //
>   create  procedure t1 ()
>   select 1;
>   //
>
> grant execute on procedure t1 to test1@'%';

call t1() works well, but if you run the above code after doing drop procedure first it gives permissions error.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this could be achieved by following steps

turn off variable automatic_sp_privileges

```
set global automatic_sp_privileges  = 0
```

Now give the execute grants on procedure to different users

drop and re-create the procedure again and the grants are still present, have also added this to ini file to make this change permanent.

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Best is to grant execute at the DB level:

grant execute on db.* to test1@'10.%';  (don't use %, too risk, use ip subnet)
This way you don't need to grant permission in SP.

Comment: want to know for specific sp only.

Comment: I don't think it will work to _add_ a `GRANT`.  That would _add_ a row to `mysql.db`.  But only one entry is used for checking grants.  That is, you cannot add a grant for '10.%' as extra info.

Comment: There is no way around. If you grant at the SP level, permission is stored in procs_priv. If you drop the SP, the permission is removed. To prevent this you need to grant at the DB level. Yes, that accoun will be able to execute all SP, but if this is done thru an App, it's pretty safe. (he/she would have to guess name of all SP and what param to pass). I've always granted execute at DB level and never had issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 things controlling it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ... SECURITY INVOKER (or DEFINER)
```

And

```
GRANT ... EXECUTE ... TO 'user'@'host';
```

If your recreation of the proc fails to include all the flags (`DETERMINISTIC`, `SECURITY`, etc), then that is lost.  And if you build it as root, with `DEFINER`, then other users cannot execute it.

I doubt if the `GRANT` is lost due to the `DROP PROCEDURE` -- after all, the `EXECUTE` is general, not specific to the proc.

Comment: it is lost if it is given to one procedure only, it remains intact if given on DB level. Can you please suggest something to control this behavior?

Comment: What is lost?  Consider filing a feature request at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: I think have to do the this.. anyways @Rick James thanks for your input